# Changing currencies vs withdrawing at ATMs in Argentina

Tags: money, argentina

My partner and I will be travelling to Argentina by the end of the year, spending two weeks in multiple locations, including Buenos Aires, El Calafate and Ushuaia.
We have all accomodations booked and paid in advance, so we'll only need pesos for food and a few minor expenses.

I read many [questions](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/62232/buying-local-currency-in-argentina) and [articles](https://discoverbuenosaires.com/using-atm-argentina) related to bringing vs withdrawing money in the country, however most are from 2016 or earlier, and the local situation is evolving quickly as far as economy in general, and inflation in particular, are concerned. *(current rate is 1 EUR <-> 41 ARS at the time this question was written)*.

We have several options, **which one would have the lowest fees** :

- withdraw pesos at local ATMs *(are they still limited to ~$2500/day ?)*
- pay all expenses with credit card (Visa)
- bring USD / EUR and change at cuevas
- set up a money transfer (Xoom or equivalent) before departing, pick it up on arrival

Comment: Get a revolut card and top-it up from home. Then use that to pay and withdraw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having travelled to Argentina in several occations there are a number of scenarios to take into consideration.

Most shops prefer cash payments. If you are going to haggle when buying things, it works better when paying cash.
When paying by card, even if it is in supermarket, you need to provide a valid ID. 
Some small shops don't even take card payments.

You might consider taking American dollars as the exchange rate is better. But check first (I normally take dollars, even though I travel from Europe).

For money transfers, there is always a fee to pay (although I might be wrong).

There are some banks in Europe that do not charge you for withdrawing money abroad, and they give you a good exchange rate, you might wish to consider this option.

I hope this helps.

All the best,